# Wanted: DB migration tool/library with reversible migrations. (to use together with Spray framework)

Tags: scala, database-migration, spray

Is there is already a tool or library which would support reversible (e.g. up and down) database migrations and could be used together with Spray framework? (And Scala, obviously)

So far, we are using [FlyWay](http://flywaydb.org/), which is working reasonably well, however cannot roll back and reapply failed migrations (a la Play framework). Which could be quite handy during early development phase, when things are changing a lot.

I had found this library: https://github.com/nafg/slick-migration-api, which references something called `ReversibleMigration`, but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I am looking for (a simple way to define up and down migrations).